# Python: Building a dictionary list based on a key and sub keys and totalling up the results based on name, region, region total and grand total

Tags: python

I have just started teaching myself Python and is currently still learning. I have very little experience in programming. In order to teach myself, I came up with the following problem. The problem is as follow...

I have 3 sellers that work in multiple regions selling stuff. I would like to know how much they are selling per region and what the total is for each person per region as well as what grand total for all of them.

I have the following data, I'm reading in from a txt file
name, region, amount

The file is sorted on name, but not on region.

- The name can be any one of 3 values John, Peter or Paul.
- The file may contain only one or all of them.
- For each person he may have sold stuff in 1 to x regions
- For each region he may have sold 1 to x items

At this stage I'm think that I should:
Read each line and...

Check if its a new name i.e. first line or going from John to Peter for example.
For each name start totalling the total of all transactions while also checking the region and adding to the regional total as well as the grand total. This is were its starts going astray, as I can have Peter with 5 sales in 3 regions:

i.e.

```
Peter r1 10
Peter r2 10
Peter r3 10
Peter r2 11
Peter R2 13
Peter R3 1
```

How do I keep track of what region I'm in, whiles also keeping track of the regional totals per sales person?

Do I use dictionary lists?

Comment: You cannot just hop into python like that. You need to learn the basics before you tackle larger problems. I recommend the free online pdf http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy.pdf

Comment: Try something first. Once you get stuck, look things up, try again. Once you get stuck again, look things up, perhaps ask here, try again.

Comment: For these kind of beginners questions, however, the [Python tutor mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor) may be very suited.

Comment: Thanks for the link AndrewGrant. That's proven quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) are two separate things.  A dictionary is a mapping of keys to values (it's a hashmap under the hood) that provides fast lookup of value by key, whereas a list is just an ordered list of arbitrary items (e.g. an arraylist)

If you want just a basic data structure to store the inventory, there a couple ways to do it, but you could use a nested dictionary, e.g. a dictionary of dictionaries where the outer dictionary maps names to a dictionary of regions and each dictionary of regions is a mapping between the region names for that person and the amount sold for that region for that person, e.g.

```
{'John': {'r2': 55}, 'Peter': {'r1': 10, 'r2': 34, 'r3': 11}}
```

A more object-oriented approach might be to create separate objects for each person and region, etc. but that would probably be overkill for what you are trying to do.

In terms of what the code to read in the transactions and populate these data structures might look like, you could do something like this:

```
# read in the transactions
with open('blah.txt') as file_obj:
    raw_data = file_obj.readlines()

inventory = {} # initialize your outer dictionary

# parse the transactions and update the inventory
for line in raw_data:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    name, region, amount = line.strip().split()

    # is r2 the same as R2?
    region = region.lower()
    # we'd like to manipulate amount as a number not a string
    amount = float(amount) 

    # create a new inner dictionary for this name, if not one already
    if not name in inventory:
        inventory[name] = {}

    # update the total for that region for that name
    inventory[name][region] = inventory[name].get(region, 0) + amount

# with the data stored this way, you can easily query 
# or calculate any totals you want, e.g.
def total_per_person_per_region(inv, name, region):
    return inv[name][region]

def total_per_person(inv, name):
    return sum(inv[name].values())

def grand_total(inv):
    return sum(total_per_person(inv, name) for name in inv)
```

Comment: Thanks Lemonhead, you gave me what I was looking for. Much appreciated.